# Java Method That Returns A Response Based On The String Input

Tags: java

I'm still quite new to programming and I haven't quite understood every method out there. as my directions say in the code, I need to print out a certain output when given a certain string input. I'm lost on what to do and i'm also having trouble just Googling it. I appreciate the help! I would just like to know what method i could implement and what to call.

```
/**
 * This method returns a response based on the string input: "Apple" =>
 * "Orange" "Hello" => "Goodbye!" "Alexander" => "The Great" "meat" =>
 * "potatoes" "Turing" => "Machine" "Special" => "\o/" Any other input
 * should be responded to with: "I don't know what to say."
 * 
 * @param input
 * The input string
 * @return Corresponding output string.
 */
public static String respond(String input) {

    // This method returns a response based on the string input:
    // "Apple" => "Orange"
    // "Hello" => "Goodbye!"
    // "Alexander" => "The Great"
    // "meat" => "potatoes"
    // "Turing" => "Machine"
    // "Special" => "\o/"
    // Any other input should be responded to with:
    // "I don't know what to say."
    return "this string is junk";
}
```

Comment: Have you learned if statements? If the input is `Apple` then return `Orange` and so on and so forth.

Comment: A map seems OK here too.

Comment: Should I be implementing Scanner to get the input? such as 'userInput.nextLine();' ?

Comment: If your assignment is just to write the method `respond` then you don't worry about it because `input` is already given to you here `respond(String input)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

```
private static final DEFAULT_RESPONSE = "I don't know what to say.";
private static final Map<String, String> RESPONSES = new HashMap<>();
static {
    RESPONSES.put("Apple", "Orange");
    RESPONSES.put("Hello", "Goodbye!"
    RESPONSES.put("Alexander", "The Great"
    RESPONSES.put("meat", "potatoes"
    RESPONSES.put("Turing", "Machine"
    RESPONSES.put("Special", "\o/"
}

public static String respond(String input) {
    String response = RESPONSES.get(input);
    if (response == null) {
        response = DEFAULT_RESPONSE;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. I have not learned anything about maps though.